# Codeigniter 3: Unknown column 'submit' in 'field list'

Tags: codeigniter, crud

I am making a CRUD application with Codeignater 3.

I have an "Add Customers" form with First name, Last name, Email address, City and a *submit* button.

The model looks like this:

```
class Customer extends CI_Model {

    public function saveCustomer($data) {
        $tbl = $this->db->dbprefix('customers');
        $this->db->insert($tbl, $data);
    }

}
```

The controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $this->load->model('Customer');
        if ($this->Customer->saveCustomer($data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('response','Customer successfully added');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('response','Failed to save customer');
        }
        return redirect('home');
}
```

The View file:

```
<?php echo form_open('home/save'); ?>

    <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('first_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <?php echo form_input('first_name', '', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'first_name', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'First name',
            ]); 
        ?>
        <?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?>                                     
    </div>

    <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('last_name')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <?php echo form_input('last_name', '', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'last_name', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Last name',
            ]); 
        ?>
        <?php echo form_error('last_name'); ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('email')) echo 'has-error';?>">
        <?php echo form_input('email', '', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'email', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Email address',
            ]); 
        ?>
        <?php echo form_error('email'); ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_input('phone', '', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'phone', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Phone number',
            ]); 
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_input('city', '', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'city', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'City',
            ]); 
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_input('address', '', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'address', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Address',
            ]); 
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class = "btn btn-primary btn-block"'); ?>
    </div>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The problem:
When I submit the form I get this error: `Unknown column 'submit' in 'field list'`

Why is that?

Comment: can you show the code for view. The thing is you didn't add the field name in `post`.

Comment: So the `$data` should be an array with all your form inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$data` as follows:

```
$data = array('column_name1' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
              'column_name2' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
              'column_name3' => $this->input->post('email'),
              'column_name4' => $this->input->post('phone'),
              'column_name5' => $this->input->post('city'),
              'column_name6' => $this->input->post('address'));
```

**NOTE:** There is no need of `return` in controller, only `redirect('home')` is needed.

Comment: If this answer helps you please support and Upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Small change in controller

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
  $data = $this->input->post();
  //unset your submit value which are come from submit btn
  if(isset($data['submit'])){unset($data['submit'])}
  if(isset($data->submit)){unset($data->submit)}
  $this->load->model('Customer');
  if ($this->Customer->saveCustomer($data)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('response','Customer successfully added');
  } else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('response','Failed to save customer');
  }
  return redirect('home');
}
```